# Why UIBarButtonItem target and action comes nil?

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I Want to press `UIBarButtonItem` programmatically in swift. I looked at the other questions asked in stackoverflow and did the same, but it didn't work.doing what i want when manually clicked but I need  click programmatically.
My example code is

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    let items =  self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems
    let item = items?.first


    UIApplication.shared.sendAction(item.action, to: item?.target, from: nil, for: nil) // not working


    _ = item.target?.perform(item.action, with: nil) // not working

    let action = item.action // result is  nil
    let target = item.target  / result is nil and item is not nil
}
```

Comment: how have you added nav bar items?

Comment: @SandeepBhandari in   viewDidLoad. ->.    let continuousVisitsButton = Util.createRightButton("ic_skip_next")
        continuousVisitsButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(continuousVisitsButtonPressed), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
        
                                                                              self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [UIBarButtonItem(customView: continuousVisitsButton), Util.createSpaceItem(), UIBarButtonItem(customView: timeFilterButton)]

Comment: Did you check the solution provided? Did it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    let items =  self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems
    let item = items?.first
    (item.customView as? UIButton).sendActions(for: .touchUpInside)
```

`self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems.first` will return `UIBarButtonItem` not your `continuousVisitsButton` button and you had set your `target` and selector to your `continuousVisitsButton` not to your `UIBarButtonItem`

In fact you simply created a `UIBarButtonItem` with customView and set it as right bar button item.

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [UIBarButtonItem(customView: continuousVisitsButton)
```

Clearly your rightBarButton item neither has target nor action hence printing returns nil.

What you need is customView inside it which has both these properties configured, So rather than trying to send touch event to bar button item access its custom view and send touch event to it, to actually trigger selector :)

. Hope this helps

Comment: thank you so much i understood my mistake have a nice day :)

Comment: @user9413194: am glad that I could help :+1

Answer (score 1):

In viewDidLoad add a navigation bar button item like this:

```
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Go", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(yourFunctionToCall))
```

now write the function for the button action

```
@objc func yourFunctionToCall() {
    print("function called...")
}
```